# How to get Local Base Path Selected `Folder` using File Browser in HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, file

I need to get `Folderpath` for selected Folder from my local System using HTML5/JS/Jquery or anything except NODEJS using file browser.

Currently i did using Node-electron but it cause an error in **centos** (i.e GCC compiler issue it affects other applications)

So i decided to fetch from **frontend** itself. but i wont able to get folder path currently i am getting relative paths of files presented inside selected folder.

Check this snippet,

```js
$('input[type=file]').change(function () {
    console.log(this.files);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" webkitdirectory directory multiple>
```

I want to get **basepath** for current selected folder. 
eg: if i select Folder called `Employee` it should give,

`/home/user/Downloads/Employee`  is there anyway to get this either using jquery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: no its not.. i want to get selected path for folder not files. i did it using node but i want to be in pure frontend html/js/jquery

Comment: Due to security considerations, the requested feature is not allowed. To my knowledge, browsers after IE6 encapsulate this info for security.

Comment: yes i know that... but i am asking is there a way to do it using any other plugin?

Comment: Not in a normal website context (because duh, security features you could easily circumvent at will, would not be proper security features to begin with.) You might have more luck with a browser extension or something like that, depending on the actual use case.

Comment: This is not possible from the front-end.